# *** TypeError: get_value_by_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attribute'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-oscar

I am using Django oscar and trying to get product attributes key and values using product.attr.get_value_by_attribute(). And I am getting above errors and I have tried to pass attribute and it still giving me an error.

My testing debugger code is as follows:

```py
(Pdb) child_product
<Product: Good Day 100 gm>
(Pdb) child_product.__dict__
{'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7fa088e1c438>, 'id': 13, 'structure': 'child', 'upc': '', 'parent_id': 12, 'title': 'Good Day 100 gm', 'slug': 'good-day-100-gm', 'description': '', 'product_class_id': None, 'rating': None, 'date_created': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 22, 15, 30, 24, 273252, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'date_updated': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 22, 15, 30, 24, 273270, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'is_discountable': True, 'attr': <oscar.apps.catalogue.product_attributes.ProductAttributesContainer object at 0x7fa088e1c470>}
(Pdb) child_product.attr
<oscar.apps.catalogue.product_attributes.ProductAttributesContainer object at 0x7fa088e1c470>
(Pdb) child_product.attr.__dict__
{'product': <Product: Good Day 100 gm>, 'initialised': False}
(Pdb) child_product.attr.__dict__
{'product': <Product: Good Day 100 gm>, 'initialised': False}
(Pdb) child_product.attr.get_values()
<QuerySet [<ProductAttributeValue: Brand: Britania>, <ProductAttributeValue: Variant Name: 100 gm x 12>]>
(Pdb) child_product.attr.get_all_attributes()
<QuerySet [<ProductAttribute: Brand>, <ProductAttribute: GST Rate>, <ProductAttribute: HSN Code>, <ProductAttribute: Liquid Content>, <ProductAttribute: Parent Company>, <ProductAttribute: Promo SKU>, <ProductAttribute: Selling Lot Size>, <ProductAttribute: Sub Brand>, <ProductAttribute: Tags>, <ProductAttribute: Variant Name>, <ProductAttribute: Weight>, <ProductAttribute: Weight Unit>]>
(Pdb) child_product.attr.get_value_by_attribute()
*** TypeError: get_value_by_attribute() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attribute'
(Pdb) child_product.attr.get_value_by_attribute(attribute="Brand")
*** ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Brand'
```

So here I am able to get value and all attributes but I don't know how to get value by attributes which I am needed.

```
child_product.attr.get_value_by_attribute()
```

So anyone has any idea about this then please help. Definitively your help will be appreciated.

Comment: It says `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Brand'`. The `attribute` is expected to be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When getting value by attributes, an instance of attribute has to be passed in the [get_value_by_attribute](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.6.7/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/product_attributes.py#L56) method. *e.g.*

```py
brand = child_product.attr.get_all_attributes().first()
child_product.attr.get_value_by_attribute(attribute=brand)
```

You can also retreive values by attribute by using [its name](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.6.7/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/abstract_models.py#L710) invoking `get` on the result of [get_values](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/1.6.7/src/oscar/apps/catalogue/product_attributes.py#L52) method. *e.g.*

```py
child_product.attr.get_values().get(attribute__name='Brand')
```

Comment: child_product.attr.get_value_by_attribute(attribute__name='Brand')
it gives ```*** TypeError: get_value_by_attribute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attribute__name'``` Do you have any idea about this

Comment: The reason for that is that get_value_by_attribute is passing down its own argument. I have updated on the way to get the Brand attribute value

Comment: Yeah now it works fine but for getting attribute name and value, attribute_summary is a better choice. But so far I am happy that my error is solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like an attribute object needs to be passed in as a parameter for get_value_by_attribute(). If 'Brand' is a slug you are trying to use to retrieve a particular attribute, use get_attribute_by_slug() to get the attribute object and then pass that to get_value_by_attribute();

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution which is very straight forward which is as follows

```
(Pdb) child_product.attribute_summary
'Brand: Nestle, Variant Name: Rs 5 x 126'

(Pdb) child_product.attribute_summary.split(',')
['Brand: Nestle', ' Variant Name: Rs 5 x 126']
```

Here I got attribute name and value which is all I want and I hope this will help you as well if you are using Django oscar.